# Find bus route number from sql queries

Tags: sql-server

I am designing bus route database. i have three tables like below,

**LocationDetails**

```
  Location ID Location Name
 ---------------------------
  1           A
  2           B
  3           C
  4           D
  5           E
  6           F
  7           G
  8           H
  9           I
```

**RouteDetails**

```
 RouteId RouteNumber
--------------------
 1       101
 2       102
 3       103
```

**RouteLocationDetails**

```
 RouteId LocationId
 ------------------
  1       3
  1       4
  1       5
  1       6
  2       2
  2       3
  2       4
  2       5
  2       6
```

I want to find the route numbers for the user entered location name.
For example if user want to travel the location from 'C' to 'F' they need to know what and all route number available for that locations, in my case 2 bus route number is available for that route (`Routenumber 101, 102`)

Can anyone tell me how to write the sql query for this?

Comment: is it gonna be only one place to another? or you will have more compliacted start and end combination?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to handle simple query like A to B, you can self join the RouteLocationDetails table

```
select r1.RouteId from RouteLocationDetails r1 join RouteLocationDetails r2 on r1.RouteId = r2.RouteId where r1.LocationId <> r2.LocationId and r1.LocationId = 'LocationNameOfC' and r2.LocationId = 'LocationNameOfF'
```

just a simple illustration, you need to join back the other two table for the necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below and make sure to pass two location names...

```
    select rd.RouteNumber,r.RouteId from #LocationDetails l
    Join 
    #RouteLocationDetails r
    on 
    l.[Location ID]=r.LocationId
    join 
    #RouteDetails rd
    on 
    r.RouteId=rd.RouteId
    where [Location Name]='C'
    or [Location Name]='F'
    group by rd.RouteNumber,r.RouteId
    having count(r.LocationId)=2
```

**Output**

```
RouteNumber RouteId
   101         1
   102         2
```

Comment: count(r.LocationId)=2 is this for what?

Comment: @shilan After grouping For each RouteId  or route number there should be two locations then only that route will have both source and destination So i have used that condition. Test it with all possibilities it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've created the following SQL Fiddle which should work in your case: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4824f/2

Creating the tables and inserting the data:

```
create table LocationDetails ([Location ID] int, [Location Name] varchar(1))
INSERT INTO LocationDetails ([Location ID],[Location Name]) VALUES(1, 'A')
INSERT INTO LocationDetails ([Location ID],[Location Name]) VALUES(2, 'B')
INSERT INTO LocationDetails ([Location ID],[Location Name]) VALUES(3, 'C')
INSERT INTO LocationDetails ([Location ID],[Location Name]) VALUES(4, 'D')
INSERT INTO LocationDetails ([Location ID],[Location Name]) VALUES(5, 'E')
INSERT INTO LocationDetails ([Location ID],[Location Name]) VALUES(6, 'F')
INSERT INTO LocationDetails ([Location ID],[Location Name]) VALUES(7, 'G')
INSERT INTO LocationDetails ([Location ID],[Location Name]) VALUES(8, 'H')
INSERT INTO LocationDetails ([Location ID],[Location Name]) VALUES(9, 'I')

create table RouteDetails (RouteId int, RouteNumber int)
INSERT INTO RouteDetails (RouteId, RouteNumber) VALUES(1, 101)
INSERT INTO RouteDetails (RouteId, RouteNumber) VALUES(2, 102)
INSERT INTO RouteDetails (RouteId, RouteNumber) VALUES(3, 103)

create table RouteLocationDetails (RouteId int, LocationId int)
INSERT INTO RouteLocationDetails (RouteId, LocationId) VALUES(1, 3)
INSERT INTO RouteLocationDetails (RouteId, LocationId) VALUES(1, 4)
INSERT INTO RouteLocationDetails (RouteId, LocationId) VALUES(1, 5)
INSERT INTO RouteLocationDetails (RouteId, LocationId) VALUES(1, 6)
INSERT INTO RouteLocationDetails (RouteId, LocationId) VALUES(2, 2)
INSERT INTO RouteLocationDetails (RouteId, LocationId) VALUES(2, 3)
INSERT INTO RouteLocationDetails (RouteId, LocationId) VALUES(2, 4)
INSERT INTO RouteLocationDetails (RouteId, LocationId) VALUES(2, 5)
INSERT INTO RouteLocationDetails (RouteId, LocationId) VALUES(2, 6)
```

Query the from and to location:

```
select RouteNumber from LocationDetails ldfrom
inner join RouteLocationDetails rldfrom on rldfrom.LocationId = ldfrom.[Location Id]
inner join RouteLocationDetails rldto on rldto.RouteId = rldfrom.RouteId
inner join LocationDetails ldto on ldto.[Location Id] = rldto.LocationId
inner join RouteDetails rd on rd.RouteId = rldto.RouteId
where ldfrom.[Location Name] = 'C' and ldto.[Location Name] = 'F'
```